# Video recording and saving the video on a server

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I just caught with a task which is how should i go about capturing a video in my app and saving it directly on some server. I have the sample code discussed in WWDC2010 but i just need some other more helpful links or tutorials to complete this task.

Please give me your opinion or share any links if you have.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the APIs that will allow you to do this. The only way is to use AVAssetWriters to segment the video. You would then stream the completed segments. These would need to be reassembled on the server side if you require a single file.

Comment: How we segment live video. Do you have any idea about it.